# continous max sum in array -Dynamic programming

Tags: c++, arrays, logic, dynamic-programming

I am following  a tutorial on dynamic programming.and following this link :
http://www.8bitavenue.com/2011/11/dynamic-programming-maximum-contiguous-sub-sequence-sum/
they have derived a relation :

```
M[j] = Max (A[j], A[j] + M[j-1])
```

but in the actual code while implementing this i cant undersatnd how they are using it .here is their implementation

```
//Initialize the first value in (M) and (b)  
M[1] = A[1];  
b[1] = 1;  

//Initialize max as the first element in (M)  
//we will keep updating max until we get the  
//largest element in (M) which is indeed our  
//MCSS value. (k) saves the (j) position of   
//the max value (MCSS)  
int max = M[1];  
int k = 1;  

//For each sub sequence ending at position (j)  
for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++)  
{  
    //M[j-1] + A[j] > A[j] is equivalent to M[j-1] > 0  
    if (M[j-1] > 0)  
    {  
        //Extending the current window at (j-1)  
        M[j] = M[j-1] + A[j];  
        b[j] = b[j-1];  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        //Starting a new window at (j)  
        M[j] = A[j];  
        b[j] = j;  
    }  

    //Update max and save (j)  
    if (M[j] > max)   
    {  
        max = M[j];  
        k = j;  
    }  
}  

print ("MCSS value = ", max,  " starts at ", b[k],  " ends at ", k);
```

***my question is how is the formula derived is used in this program ??***

shouldn't they use a for something like this :

```
for i in A:
  M[j] = Max (A[j], A[j] + M[j-1])
```

Comment: Unclear connection to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123505/dynamic-programming-confusion/30123850#30123850).

Comment: hi, Ami this question is in fact related to previous one . the problem is after understanding all the theory behind the given article when i saw the implementation it looks completely different i mean why can't they use the formula they are deriving???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is already given in this line:

```
//M[j-1] + A[j] > A[j] is equivalent to M[j-1] > 0
```

The if statement chooses the bigger value between A[j] and M[j-1]+A[j].
 Would this be more clear to you?

```
if (M[j-1] + A[j] > A[j]) // is exact the same thing as M[j-1] > 0, but less elegant
{   
     M[j] = M[j-1] + A[j];
     b[j] = b[j-1];
}
else
{
    M[j] = A[j];
    b[j] = j;
}
```